# Images grid with dynamic scaling of each image

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, image-gallery

I found a images grid at the site http://www.danielkennedy.com/

Images there fits perfectly for each line and recalculates on window size changes.

I want to implement that on my site. I tried to use Isotope plugin with horizontal orientation (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonryhorizontal.html), but it doesn't helps.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to implement masonry galley on `http://www.danielkennedy.com` to your site, you may consider using *layoutMode: 'fitRows'*.

Items are arranged into rows and rows will progress vertically when your screen resized.

Check my code example here

```
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoKqNV
```

Hope this helps